# Install Drupal 8 Commerce with composer

Tags: drupal, composer-php, drupal-8, commerce

I want to install Drupal Commerce on my new D8, I do it with Composer like recommended in the guide here (https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/install-update/installation), but I get this :

> $ composer require drupal/commerce
>
> [InvalidArgumentException]   Could not find package drupal/commerce.
>
> Did you mean this?
> drupal/commerce_taxcloud

I'm using Wamp64 on Windows 10, if it matters.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try whit:

```
composer require 'drupal/commerce:^2.21'
```

Comment: And with quadruple ^ ? Or double ^ ?

composer require 'drupal/commerce:^^^^2.21'